# Text reader for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my first coding experience. I would like to visualize the object while moving according to data comes from another source.

I want to choose from the dataset and would like to use values in the parenthesis:

```
Parent: bp
     Children (0):
        Static Translation: (15.0503, 34.1802, -118.183)
```

To do it I tried to use:

```
if (records[i].Contains("Parent: bp") && records[i + 1].Contains("Children(0):")) { }
            string[] array = records[i + 2].Split(',');
                array[1] = array[1].Split('(')[1];
                array[2] = array[2].Split(',',',')[1];
                array[3] = "0";
            steps.Add(
                new Step()
                {
                    speed = float.Parse("2"),
                    destination = new Vector3(float.Parse(array[1]), float.Parse(array[2]), float.Parse(array[3]))
```

I would be happy if anyone can help me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please specify what is the problem you're having so users can answer your question

Comment: Thank you, I want to create arrays [1,2,3] from the values in parenthesis.

Comment: This is the thing. How to move object according to the text?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I cannot comment due to not having enough karma, but I would suggest using [Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) for this, as lists are almost always as capable as arrays and prevent a lot of mistakes that arrays don't. Without more info as to what exact problem you're having, there isn't much anyone can help with here. Are you simply trying to take an array of elements and separate each element into a new array?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Exactly the same thing. For that part of the text, I'm trying to define array[1]=15.0503, array[2]=34.1802, array[3]=118.183